# Convert user's entered time into a Unix timestamp

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that converts readable time, that user enters into a Unix timestamp.

It should work like this:

```
string time;
int unixtime;
getline(cin, time) // User enters time in a format as HH:MM, say 15:00
??? // Today's date gets appended to time, so July 11th, 2021
??? // Date gets converted to Unix timestamp, stored in a variable of type int 'unixtime'

cout << unixtime;

// Output
1626015600
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Is the user-entered time of day measured in the user's local time zone, or measured in UTC?  Your example uses 15:00 UTC.  Whatever the answer is, can we assume that the definition of "today's date" uses the same time zone as the user-entered time?

Comment: You can convert string to tm struct with `strptime`.
You can then convert tm struct to unix timestamp with `mktime`.

https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strptime.html
https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [`std::get_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time):

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip> // std::get_time
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    // get current time
    std::time_t now = std::time(nullptr);
    std::tm ut = *std::localtime(&now); // or std::gmtime for UTC

    // get hour and minute from the user
    if(std::cin >> std::get_time(&ut, "%H:%M")) {
        // convert back to time_t
        std::time_t unixtime = std::mktime(&ut);
        std::cout << unixtime << '\n';
    }
}
```